# Convert Date to dd/mm/yyyy format in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, object

This date issue is giving me a hard time. i am getting the below value from sql table.

```
var CurrentDate = 2017-04-25T00:00:00
```

I need to convert this to 04/25/2017 at the UI. I tried using various date methods but didnt get wat i want. Can someone pls shed some light. this is wat i tried.

```
var date_new = new Date(CurrentDate);
date_new= date_new.toLocaleDateString();
```

Comment: When I run your code (putting ' ' around the CurrentDate string), and print date_new to the console, I get what you want ('04/25/2017'). Are you getting an error, or a string that's not what you want?

Comment: @Rihana, you may try executing the snippet from my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat)

```js
var CurrentDate = "2017-04-25T00:00:00";
var date_new = new Date(CurrentDate);
document.write(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date_new));
```

Comment: it is giving output as 24th instead of 25

Comment: @Rihana, you may execute it through the "Run code snippet" option to verify. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to parse your dates and times, it's very easy and powerful.

Install moment and then require it in your js.

```
const moment = require('moment')

const currentDate = '2017-04-25T00:00:00'
const parsedCurrentDate = moment(currentDate).format('l')
```

And you will get: `'4/25/2017'` stored in your `parsedCurrentDate` variable.

Just show that in your ui.

There are other formatting options, just take a look at the moment's [website](https://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just surround your date in quotes.

`var CurrentDate = '2017-04-25T00:00:00';`